# Web WhatsApp doesn't show behind proxy

Tags: ssl, squid, man-in-the-middle, whatsapp

I have proxy with SSL bump configured. While this is on, WhatApp we doesn't show, why?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Because WhatsApp Web depends on [web sockets](http://www.websocket.org/) and those don't work with an [Interception Proxy](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/InterceptionProxy).